# fileUploader javascript - how to override params?

Tags: javascript, jquery, file-upload

I'm usinag plugin [Fileuploader](https://github.com/valums/file-uploader). I have a trouble how to change on of his attribute (Class). Id must be the same as `$('#jquery-wrapped-fine-uploader')`'s attr Id (i.e. `<div id="jquery-wrapped-fine-uploader" class="main_pic">`). Is there a way how to get this value?

```
$('#jquery-wrapped-fine-uploader').fineUploader({
    request: {
        endpoint: '../../main/fileupload',
        params: {
            'class' : (function(){

                var class = 5;
                /* Заместо 5 надо поставить атрибут class */
                /* i.e. insert here an Class attr */
                /* $(this).closest('#jquery-wrapped-fine-uploader').attr('class')
                    does not work :-(
                 */

                return id;
            })(),
        }
    },
    failedUploadTextDisplay: {
        mode: 'custom',
        maxChars: 256,
        responseProperty: 'error',
        enableTooltip: true
    },
    debug: true,
});
```

})

Comment: It's not really clear what you are asking.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It must be work - `.attr('class')`.
The problem is - `$(this).closest('#jquery-wrapped-fine-uploader').attr('class')`.
What does 'this' mean in this context? If it's `'#jquery-wrapped-fine-uploader'` you must write `$(this).attr('class')`.

Try to use something like this:

```
    $('#jquery-wrapped-fine-uploader').each(function(){
    var self = this;
    var className = $(self).attr('class');

    $(self).fineUploader({
        request: {
            endpoint: '../../main/fileupload',
            params: {
                'class' : (function(){

                    var class = className;

                    return id;
                })(),
            }
        },
        failedUploadTextDisplay: {
            mode: 'custom',
            maxChars: 256,
            responseProperty: 'error',
            enableTooltip: true
        },
        debug: true,
    });
});
```

P.S. Короче если по русски - то не понятно что объект "this". Поэтому попробуй код который написан выше. Правда не гарантирую что он без ошибок.